# TypeError: 'Answer' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

```
class AnswerListFilterForUserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):        
        user = request.query_params.get('user')
        data = Answer.objects.filter(question = pk).filter(username = 
        user).order_by('created_at').last()
        serializer= AnswerFilterSerializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can i get last data from my Answer Model
When i am use `last()` then error occurs That "TypeError: 'Answer' object is not iterable"
Help me out of this

Comment: It's because you used `many=True` in serializer. With this option your serializer expects that `data` will be iterable object (list, tuple etc), but yor `data` is an `Answer` model instance

Answer (score -1):

use **latest()** method instead **last()** method.
Hope this will work.

see the official Docs of Django for more clarity https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest